# index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy realizando una función que me permita contar las veces que se repiten los elementos dentro de un array, pero me sale el "index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4", no comprendo el error. observo el código y aparentemente todo está bien, se supone que reviso un arreglo como argumento de la función y esos elementos (numeros enteros positivos) son los que debo contar. Les dejo mi código:

```
def conteo_pedidos(pedidos):
  """
  pedidos: un arreglo de NumPy con valores enteros no negativos. Contiene IDs de productos pedidos, pueden estar repetidos.

  Retorna un arreglo con el conteo de los IDs del arreglo de pedidos. 
  El arreglo resultante codifica cada conteo en su posición de ID correspondiente.
  """
  ### ESCRIBA SU CÓDIGO AQUÍ ###  
  # Reemplace la palabra None por el código correspondiente
  # ~ 6 líneas de código
  
  # Obtenga el valor máximo del arreglo 'pedidos'
  máximo = len(pedidos)

  # Calcule el tamaño del arreglo resultante 
  tamaño = np.array(pedidos)
  tamaño = tamaño.shape

  # Cree un arreglo de ceros con ese tamaño para la guardar su respuesta
  conteos = np.zeros(tamaño)

  # Recorra cada ID en el arreglo de 'pedidos' e incremente en 1 la cantidad 
  # correspondiente a ese ID en el arreglo de 'conteos' en cada iteración
  for i in pedidos:
    if i in conteos:
      conteos[i] +=1

    else:
      conteos[i] = 1


  ### FIN DEL CÓDIGO ###

  return conteos
```

El resultado que obtuve fue el siguiente:

```
# CELDA DE PRUEBAS 
print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6])))

print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([2, 2, 3, 4])))

print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3])))

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-81ac5752ce1a> in <module>()
      2 print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6])))
      3 
----> 4 print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([2, 2, 3, 4])))
      5 
      6 print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3])))

<ipython-input-15-8f9842f29e04> in conteo_pedidos(pedidos)
     28 
     29     else:
---> 30       conteos[i] = 1
     31 
     32 

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

Comment: te estas pasando del límite de la lista. Estas utilizando los números de tu numpy array como índices y eso no es correcto

Comment: cambia esto `conteos = np.zeros(tamaño)` por esto `conteos = {}` y se soluciona todo y es mucho más entendible. O has `conteos[i-1] = 1` ya sea para actualizar la cantidad o agregar datos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me corre
Pero resulta que mi salida debe ser la siguiente:

`
[0. 1. 1. 3. 0. 2. 1.]
[0. 0. 2. 1. 1.]
[0. 1. 1. 1.]
`
Para los estos arrays que recibe:

`print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6])))

print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([2, 2, 3, 4])))

print(conteo_pedidos(np.array([1, 2, 3])))`

Y creando el diccionario, me retorna:

`{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 5: 2, 6: 1}
{2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}`

Comment: Listo, cambié el 1 por un 0. Pero me retorna un diccionario y debe ser una lista, esto lo puedo transformar?

Comment: Claramente, con `diccionario.values()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def conteo_pedidos(pedidos):

conteos = np.zeros(np.max(pedidos) + 1)

for i in (pedidos):

    conteos[i] += 1 if i in pedidos else 0

return conteos
```

Comment: ¿Cual era el error? ¿Cómo lo corriges?